# How to plot a fanchart like on Wikipedia page

Tags: r, plot, lattice

How can I plot a fanchart as displayed on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_chart_%28statistics%29#Example)?

I have installed the `nlme` package with its `MathAchieve` dataset, but I cannot find the commands for plotting this graph.

The `nlme` pdf file is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/nlme.pdf).

I also checked [this link](http://www.fischer-zim.ch/studien/Neue-Grafiken-I-1003-Info.htm) but it is non-english.

With the `fan.plot` function from the `plotrix` package, I could only draw pie charts: 
https://sites.google.com/site/distantyetneversoclose/excel-charts/the-pie-doughnut-combination-a-fan-plot

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow. That looks pretty kewl. If you don't get an answer in the next two days, why not post on Rhelp. Jim Lemon is the premier graphics author for this sort of new plotting function and he does not visit SO. His `plotrix` package has bunch of specialized charting functions.

Comment: The example data (MathAchieve) comes from nlme, but the plot was made with the lattice package. It's unfortunate that the authors of that plot did not share the code.

Comment: I found an example in the gamlss package by searching with Google. Bummer, it has very little resemblance to that chart.

Comment: The package I tried was plotrix (fan.plot function). I have corrected this in my question above.

Comment: The 'fanplot' package is different and it seems to be for prediction/forecasting as on this page: http://gjabel.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/bank-of-england-fan-charts-in-r/

Comment: that guy has some really nice looking graphics. unfortunately, also looks like he goes to great lengths not to share the code

Comment: @rawr ??? all the code to reproduce the plots are right there? if you want the underlying code for the function (as with any function in an R package) type fanplot:::fan in R.

Comment: hey guy, I was actually referring to the original image that wolfram fischer did, http://www.fischer-zim.ch/grafik/index.htm, sorry. @gjabel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having thought about this a bit more since my previous answer, I've come up with a simpler way of producing multipanel (if appropriate) fanplots, overlaid on a `levelplot`, as shown in the [Wikipedia Fan chart page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_chart_%28statistics%29#Example). This approach works with a `data.frame` that has two independent variables and zero or more conditioning variables that separate data into panels.

First we define a new panel function, `panel.fanplot`.

```
panel.fanplot <- function(x, y, z, zmin, zmax, subscripts, groups, 
                          nmax=max(tapply(z, list(x, y, groups), 
                            function(x) sum(!is.na(x))), na.rm=T), 
                          ...) {

  if(missing(zmin)) zmin <- min(z, na.rm=TRUE)
  if(missing(zmin)) zmax <- max(z, na.rm=TRUE)
  get.coords <- function(a, d, x0, y0) {
    a <- ifelse(a <= 90, 90 - a, 450 - a)
    data.frame(x = x0 + d * cos(a / 180 * pi), 
               y = y0 + d * sin(a / 180 * pi))
  }

  z.scld <- (z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin) * 360
  fan <- aggregate(list(z=z.scld[subscripts]), 
                   list(x=x[subscripts], y=y[subscripts]), 
                   function(x) 
                     c(n=sum(!is.na(x)),
                       quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), na.rm=TRUE) - 90))

  panel.levelplot(fan$x, fan$y, 
                  (fan$z[, '50%'] + 90) / 360 * (zmax - zmin) + zmin,
                  subscripts=seq_along(fan$x), ...)
  lapply(which(!is.na(fan$z[, '50%'])), function(i) {
    with(fan[i, ], {
      poly <- rbind(c(x, y), 
                    get.coords(seq(z[, '25%'], z[, '75%'], length.out=200), 
                               0.3, x, y))
      lpolygon(poly$x, poly$y, col='gray10', border='gray10', lwd=3)
      llines(get.coords(c(z[, '50%'], 180 + z[, '50%']), 0.3, x, y),
             col='black', lwd=3, lend=1)
      llines(get.coords(z[, '50%'], c(0.3, (1 - z[, 'n']/nmax) * 0.3), x, y), 
             col='white', lwd=3)
    })
  })
}
```

Now we create some dummy data and call `levelplot`:

```
d <- data.frame(z=runif(1000), 
                x=sample(5, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                y=sample(5, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                grp=sample(4, 1000, replace=TRUE))

colramp <- colorRampPalette(c('#fff495', '#bbffaa', '#70ffeb', '#72aaff', 
                              '#bf80ff'))

levelplot(z ~ x*y|as.factor(grp), d, groups=grp, asp=1, col.regions=colramp, 
          panel=panel.fanplot, zmin=min(d$z, na.rm=TRUE), 
          zmax=max(d$z, na.rm=TRUE), at=seq(0, 1, 0.2))
```

It's important to pass the conditioning variable (that separates plots into panels) to `levelplot` via the argument `group`, as shown above with the variable `grp`, in order for sample sizes to be calculated (shown by white line length).

[image: fanplot1]

And here's how we would mimic the Wikipedia plot:

```
library(nlme)
data(MathAchieve)
MathAchieve$SESfac <- as.numeric(cut(MathAchieve$SES, seq(-2.5, 2, 0.5)))
MathAchieve$MEANSESfac <- 
  as.numeric(cut(MathAchieve$MEANSES, seq(-1.25, 1, 0.25)))
levels(MathAchieve$Minority) <- c('Non-minority', 'Minority')
MathAchieve$group <- 
  as.factor(paste0(MathAchieve$Sex, ', ', MathAchieve$Minority))

colramp <- colorRampPalette(c('#fff495', '#bbffaa', '#70ffeb', '#72aaff', 
                              '#bf80ff'))

levelplot(MathAch ~ SESfac*MEANSESfac|group, MathAchieve, 
          groups=group, asp=1, col.regions=colramp, 
          panel=panel.fanplot, zmin=0, zmax=28, at=seq(0, 25, 5),
          scales=list(alternating=1, 
                      tck=c(1, 0), 
                      x=list(at=seq(1, 11) - 0.5, 
                             labels=seq(-2.5, 2, 0.5)),
                      y=list(at=seq(1, 11) - 0.5, 
                             labels=seq(-1.25, 1, 0.25))),
          between=list(x=1, y=1), strip=strip.custom(bg='gray'),
          xlab='Socio-economic status of students',
          ylab='Mean socio-economic status for school')
```

[image: fanplot2]

Comment: great job - hope i get a chance to use this

Answer (score 5):

I can think of a couple of ways of going about this with `lattice`. You could either use `xyplot` and fill panels with `panel.fill`, or you can use `levelplot`. The polygons themselves have to be added with a custom panel and `lpolygon`. Here's how I've done it with `levelplot`. I'm really a `lattice` novice, though, and there may very well be some shortcuts that I don't know about.

Because I'm using `levelplot`, we first create a matrix containing median `MathAch` scores for each combination of `MEANSES` and `SES`. These will be used to plot the cell colours.

```
library(lattice)
library(nlme)
data(MathAchieve)
```

Below, I convert `SES` and `MEANSES` into factors using `cut`, with breakpoints as in the Wikipedia example.

```
MathAchieve$SESfac <- as.numeric(cut(MathAchieve$SES, seq(-2.5, 2, 0.5)))
MathAchieve$MEANSESfac <- as.numeric(cut(MathAchieve$MEANSES, 
                                         seq(-1.25, 1, 0.25)))
```

I'm not sure how to plot the four panels as on the Wikipedia page, so I'll just subset to non-minority females:

```
d <- subset(MathAchieve, Sex=='Female' & Minority=='No')
```

To convert this dataframe to a matrix, I `split` it to a list and then coerce back to a matrix with the appropriate dimensions. Each cell of the matrix contains the median `MathAch` for a particular combination of `SESfac` and `MEANSESfac`.

```
l <- split(d$MathAch, list(d$SESfac, d$MEANSESfac))
m.median <- matrix(sapply(l, median), ncol=9)
```

When we use `levelplot` we will have access to `x` and `y`, being the coordinates of the "current" cell. In order to pass the vector of `MathAch` to `levelplot`, so that a polygon can be plotted for each cell, I create a matrix (same dimensions as `m.median`) of lists, where each cell is a list containing a `MathAch` vector.

```
m <- matrix(l, ncol=9)
```

Below we create a color ramp as used by Wolfram Fischer in the example on Wikipedia.

```
colramp <- colorRampPalette(c('#fff495', '#bbffaa', '#70ffeb', '#72aaff', 
                              '#bf80ff'))
```

Now we define the custom panel function. I've commented throughout to explain:

```
fanplot <- function(x, y, z, subscripts, fans, ymin, ymax, 
                    nmax=max(sapply(fans, length)), ...) {
  # nmax is the maximum sample size across all combinations of conditioning
  # variables. For generality, ymin and ymax are limits of the circle around 
  # around which fancharts are plotted. 
  # fans is our matrix of lists, which are used to plot polygons.
  get.coords <- function(a, d, x0, y0) {
    a <- ifelse(a <= 90, 90 - a, 450 - a)
    data.frame(x = x0 + d * cos(a / 180 * pi), 
               y = y0 + d * sin(a / 180 * pi))
  }
  # getcoords returns coordinates of one or more points, given angle(s), 
  # (i.e., a), distances (i.e., d), and an origin (x0 and y0).

  panel.levelplot(x, y, z, subscripts, ...)

  # Below, we scale the raw vectors of data such that ymin thru ymax map to 
  # 0 thru 360. We then calculate the relevant quantiles (i.e. 25%, 50% and 75%).
  smry <- lapply(fans, function(y) {
    y.scld <- (y - ymin)/(ymax - ymin) * 360
    quantile(y.scld, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) - 90
  })

  # Now we use get.coords to determine relevant coordinates for plotting 
  # polygons and lines. We plot a white line inwards from the circle's edge,
  # with length according to the ratio of the sample size to nmax.
  mapply(function(x, y, smry, n) {
    if(!any(is.na(smry))) {
      lpolygon(rbind(c(x, y), 
                     get.coords(seq(smry['25%'], smry['75%'], length.out=200), 
                                0.3, x, y)), col='gray10', lwd=2)
      llines(get.coords(c(smry['50%'], 180 + smry['50%']), 0.3, 
                        x, y), col=1, lwd=3)
      llines(get.coords(smry['50%'], c(0.3, (1 - n/nmax) * 0.3), 
                        x, y), col='white', lwd=3)
    }
  }, x=x, y=y, smry=smry, n=sapply(fans, length))
}
```

And finally use this custom panel function within `levelplot`:

```
levelplot(m.median, fans=m, ymin=0, ymax=28,
          col.regions=colramp, at=seq(0, 25, 5), panel=fanplot, 
          scales=list(tck=c(1, 0), 
                      x=list(at=seq_len(ncol(m.median) + 1) - 0.5, 
                             labels=seq(-2.5, 2, 0.5)),
                      y=list(at=seq_len(nrow(m.median) + 1) - 0.5, 
                             labels=seq(-1.25, 1, 0.25))), 
          xlab='Socio-economic status of students',
          ylab='Mean socio-economic status for the school')
```

[image]

I haven't coloured cells grey if they have sample size < 7, as was done for the equivalent plot on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_chart_%28statistics%29#Example), but this could be done with `lrect` if needed.

Comment: I've provided a new solution that I think is more user-friendly, but will keep this one here to demonstrate the alternative approach.